# Remote access to an iMac Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, imac, remote-desktop

So I have a friend, who has an iMac Pro with high specs at his home and I thought about accessing his iMac Pro from my Macbook Pro via some kind of remote desktop service. I would do some rather extensive video editing on that iMac Pro, for which my Macbook Pro is just too slow currently as its a rather old one from 2016. My question now is how i would be able to access that iMac Pro from my Macbook Pro, so I can basically do some kind of screen sharing and use Final Cut Pro installed on that iMac Pro. I tried downloading Remote Desktop from the store, but I can only make it work, when both of our devices are in the same network (we tried it on wifi), but I just wasnt able to make it work when we are not both in the same network, which would be the actual case at hand, because I would need to access his iMac Pro from anywhere. I have seen something with SSH, but isnt that only for servers and such? Either way I just wanted to ask, if someone knows how to best get this setup working.

Answer (score 0):

Use either Screens and Screens Connect or TeamViewer.

- https://edovia.com/en/screens-connect/ and https://edovia.com/en/screens-mac/
- https://www.teamviewer.com/

Both of these broker connections and work with routers to establish connections across the internet and private networks where routing is not set up for ARD.